# Using graphics on a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jpanel, java-2d

I'm trying to draw a rectangle to a JPanel using the following code:

```
JPanel background = new JPanel();
Graphics2D g = null;
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g2d.drawRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
```

When I try to compile it I get the error

java.lang.NullPointerException   on the set colour line.

I have also tried this but i get the same bug

```
JPanel background = new JPanel();
Graphics bg = background.getGraphics();
bg.setColor(Color.BLACK);
bg.drawRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
```

can anyone help me fix this bug?

Comment: In the first case g is set to null and g2d is therefore also null -> NPE at g2d.setColor

Comment: In general I'd recommend to write your own panel and overwrite the paint() method instead of doing whatever you're doing at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To draw on a JPanel, you need to override `paintComponent()`. You can override it on the fly as follows or create a subclass:

```
JPanel background = new JPanel()
{
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.drawRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
    }
};
```

Comment: <cough>super.paintComponent</cough>

Comment: Still something's missing, but the basics are there ;) +1

Comment: You also need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of the panel, so layout managers will know how to use the component properly.

Answer (score 4):

Create a subclass of JPanel, and override the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method. Only paint from this method, using the `Graphics` passed as argument to the method, that you can safely cast to `Graphics2D`:

```
JPanel background = new JPanel() {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.drawRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Custom painting in Swing is normally done by overriding the paintComponent method of any class that extend JComponent. Unless you have some need to do otherwise, it is recommended that you extend from something like a JPanel.

```
public class MyPanel exends JPanel {
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(800, 600);
    }
}
```

Take a look at [Performing custom painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) for more details

Comment: +1 For overriding `getPreferredSize()`. Now `pack()` can re-size the JFrame to show the rectangle ;)

Comment: @Eng.Fouad It's the only reason I posted (apart from the first two answers were missing `super.paintComponent` at the time ;))